# How to query all images from getExternalFilesDir path through MediaStore

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-storage

I am writing a camera and gallery app, following the official Google documentation. The problem is that it mostly focuses on how to take a picture and how to save it in memory. I am saving them in the application external memory through getExternalFilesDir().

What I am now trying to do is simpy query that directory in which taken photos are saved, through MediaStore, in order to display all the pictures in there in a recycler view. But I can't seem to find anywhere an explanation on how to do the retrieval. There is something wrong with the Uri that I probably didn't understand well, and I don't know how to solve. Even in here https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#PrivateFiles the article only talks about saving files in the various storage options, but not about retrieving them.

Here is the code of how I save the files:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";

    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",   /* suffix */
            storageDir     /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

This is the function that actually sends the intent (and then onActivityResult handles the returned data):

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    final String TAG = "dispatchTakePic: ";
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating a file");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        // Authority has to be exactly like in manifest
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code where I'm trying to get the information about the photos taken:

```
private void populatePhotoArray() {
    final String TAG = "popPhotoArray: ";
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    String photo_id, photo_title, photo_path = "";

    final String[] PHOTOGRAPHS_PROJECTION = {
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    File photographsDirectory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
    Uri photographsUri = Uri.fromFile(photographsDirectory);
    //Uri photographsUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //Uri photographsUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
    final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
            photographsUri,
            PHOTOGRAPHS_PROJECTION,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder);

    Log.d(TAG, "created the projection");

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            photo_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
            photo_title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE));
            photo_path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

            // save to photo list
            applicationPhotosList.add(new Photographs(photo_id, photo_title, photo_path));
            Log.d(TAG, "new photo added");
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "Photo array filled up");
    }
    else if (cursor == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "No photos present, cursor is null");
        Toast.makeText(this, "No photos present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Looks like trying to transform the path of getExternalFileDir() into an Uri doesn't work. The cursor is empty. But MediaStore only has MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and that's not suitable as that queries the whole device memory, while I only need that particular directory in which my app is saving the pictures taken. What am I missing? It cannot be that hard, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to retrieve the images from a specific folder w/o using the cursor and I think its more faster.

```
    private fun getAllShownImagesPath(): ArrayList<String> {

    var filePath: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>()
    val path = File(getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).path, "BacFo Camera")
    if (path.exists()) {

        for (i in path.list().iterator()) {

            filePath?.add("" + path.toString() + "/" + i)
        }
    }

    return filePath!!
    }
```

` 
In "fileNames" you have the path of all images or videos whatever you have saved in the specific folder

Comment: we know have a paths of all images from a specific folder and we can use Glide to upload them in imageView.